# How do i fetch userdata from MySQL database and work with Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: mysql, botframework, bots, chatbot, web-chat

I'm working on designing a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework. I want to display user data from MySQL database and display whenever an option is used in bot options. Like username. How do i do that?

Comment: check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938472/saving-bot-state-data-in-mysql-with-net

Comment: @ShanmukhGudivada - Are you still working on this? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney I am indeed working on this. I still haven't figured out a way yet. Feel free to suggest. Really need a solution.

Comment: @ShanmukhGudivada - Your question is still unclear. What do you mean by "bot options"? What is your database used for? How would the bot know which username to retrieve from the database? What language is your bot written in? Does your question really have anything to do with bots or are you just asking how any web app can use a MySQL API? You really should try to expand your question to explain what you're trying to do and why. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @KyleDelaney Let me explain this very aptly. I'm the head of R&D team in my company. I'm trying to make a bot for internal communications. I've designed the bot using Bot composer. I want to basically personalise the bot to the user's comfort. So by this means i want to greet the logged in user with their name. So to do this i need to get data from database which is MySQL. All i'm asking is how do i code the bot to say hi (name of the user)  and give a personalised experience. To do this i need to get data from database. So how do i do this? Connect to database via bot and pull the data.

Comment: @ShanmukhGudivada - It sounds like you're saying you have a table that can be used to look up user information based on the user ID the bot receives from the channel. Is that correct? It's unclear what part of that you need help with. Do you need help accessing the user ID in the turn context? Do you need help using your database's API? Do you need help creating an HTTP step in Composer? Also, what channel are you using?

Comment: All I want to do is run the bot in my local intranet without connecting to Intenet(Azure). I want to embed the bot link within my intranet portal running on PHP. The end user will login to the portal and their UserId is stored in the session. Upon invoking the Bot on the portal I want to extract the userid from the session and greet the user by name. The user  is then presented with options to choose from  and when the User selects an option we call an api to fetch data from database.

Comment: @ShanmukhGudivada - All right well that sounds very different from the question you asked, and you still haven't told me what channel/client you're using. Is it Direct Line / Web Chat? I think it would be a good idea to heavily edit your question to explain what you're actually trying to do, or to ask a new question. Did you read the guide I linked to earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok. let me rephrase. I'm using Web Chat. See i want to let the bot know which user is using the bot and greet him. i'm using a database and it has the user data. I dont know how to connect to the database via chatbot and greet the user.Still unclear?

Comment: Yes, it is still unclear because you haven't answered most of the questions I've asked. Please edit your question to include more information instead of carrying on a long conversation here in the comments. Are you saying you don't know how to access the API of your own MySQL database? You haven't told us anything about how you've set up your MySQL database server, but a quick search brought me to this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-connectors.html

Comment: @ShanmukhGudivada - Are you still working on this?